# FireBaseUI java

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am writing a test application on Firebase (Android+Java). I was faced with what problem. I use from Firebaseui for registration/authentication (https://firebase.google.com/docs/adroid/firebaseui?hl=en&authuser=0). As Sign In Method, the Google account and email/password set. So. With Google, everything works without problems and registration and authentication. And with Email/Password I registered without problems. Registered user appeared in Firebase Console, for example Test@mail.ru. But, if I try to go under a previously registered user Test@mail.ru, then I have a form of registration. Although I expect to see that I just ask me to enter a password, because This user has already been registered earlier. How to fix this bug? Or I, maybe something overlooked, for example, did not connect any library?

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {
                    onSignInResult(result);
                }
            }
    );

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            signOut();
        }
    }

    private void onSignInResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {
        IdpResponse response = result.getIdpResponse();
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
            // Successfully signed in
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            if (response != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + response.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void signOut(){
        AuthUI.getInstance()
                .signOut(this)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

// Create and launch sign-in intent
                        Intent signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                .build();
                        signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
                    }
                });

    }

    public void onClickLogout(View view) {
        signOut();
    }
}
```

No autentification FireBaseUI with email/password

Comment: Also posted on https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/2144